# Android error: Application is not installed on your phone

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I am getting this error when trying to install my exported unsigned application on tablet pc (running Android 4.04. version). App is normally installing and running in Android emulator in Eclipse. I tried removing and reinstalling it, but that didn't help either. Atached is my AndroidManifest.xml since problem is often there (but I can't see any duplicate code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />    

        <application 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">        
            <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"            
                android:name=".ListaProizvoda" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name="DetaljiProizvoda"></activity>
            <activity android:name="GMapsActivity"></activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        </application>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>       

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing suspicious I see is the uses-library tag, do you have the Google Maps lib in your tablet? (if yes then you should have the following files in it)

```
/system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml
/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
```

Without the lib the apk installation will fail with INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error.

Comment: i see folder com.google.android.maps in android/data folder of system so i doubt it is problem. Every android OS comes with this lib i believe. tablet is btw from China. Error is one i've stated at the top, not install_failed_missing_shared_library one

Comment: "from China"...dude that's exactly what I worried about, Google services are sort of "banned" in China mainland so customized devices for the market usually don't have GMS apps installed. Please run "adb shell ls -l -s /system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml" to see if the file is really there in the tablet. And try to install you apk by the "adb install" command if it fails there will be a clear error message like the one I mentioned.

Comment: i've just tried to install same thing on HTC phone and it still won't install. So there is nothing wrong with chinese tablet pc, obviously. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: just to add this: app is normally working when installing .apk on phone directly from Eclipse. Strange, isn't it? I've checked "installing apps from unknown sources" and "USB debugging" in phone's OS (android 2.3)